# How to make the loading screen to disappear when my data is loaded in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to build a loading screen when no data is displayed. But it's not working, it keeps loading forever. How to make the loading screen to disappear when my data is loaded?

This is my **C# code**

```
        if (Clublistview.ItemsSource == null)
        {
            try
            {
                base.OnAppearing();
                await setClubs(Clublistview);

                overlay.IsVisible = false;
                Clublistview.IsVisible = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //MessagingCenter
                await DisplayAlert("Error",
                    "There seems to be an error, please check your internet connection.",
                    "OK");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            overlay.IsVisible = true;
            Clublistview.IsVisible = false;
        }
```

This is the **XAML code**

```
 <ListView  x:Name="Clublistview" HasUnevenRows="true" ItemSelected="OnItemSelected" ItemsSource="{Binding Id}" IsVisible="true">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell Height="55">
                            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="White"
                            Orientation="Vertical">
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="2,2,2,2">
                                    <Image Source="{Binding Logo}" IsVisible="true" WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50"/>

                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="20" x:Name="BtnClub" 
                                         TextColor="Black" />

                                        <Label HorizontalOptions="Start" Text="Select for more info" FontSize="10"/>
                                        <!--<Button BackgroundColor="White" TextColor="Black"  HorizontalOptions="Start" x:Name="btnInfo" 
                                        Text="Select for more info" FontSize="10" Clicked="OnInfoClicked" CommandParameter="{Binding Id}"/>-->
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
            <ContentView x:Name="overlay" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" IsVisible="false">
                <ActivityIndicator  IsRunning="True" IsVisible="True" Color="Black" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
              </ContentView>
```

Comment: Add your XAML code, please.

Comment: Hi I've added the xaml code

Comment: If `Clublistview.ItemsSource` doesn't null you are showing loader - strange for me or I didn't get something. Are you able to reach this line `overlay.IsVisible = false;` in `try` block in debug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like this code is placed on the `OnAppearing` method of your `ContentPage`. If that's the case, it's only going to be called 1 time as the page is shown. Assuming that `Clublistview.ItemsSource` is not null, then this code gets executed:

```
overlay.IsVisible = true;
Clublistview.IsVisible = false;
```

This means that your overlay is visible and the `ActivityIndicator` will be spinning. If this is not in `OnAppearing` then I am not sure when you are calling the method it is in.

You might want to do something like this instead:

```
public override async void OnAppearing()
{
   base.OnAppearing();

   // Show your overlay
   overlay.IsVisible = true;
   Clublistview.IsVisible = false;

   // Load the items into the ItemsSource
   await setClubs(Clublistview);

   // Hide the overlay
   overlay.IsVisible = false;
   Clublistview.IsVisible = true;
}
```

You can achieve this type of behavior in a cleaner way with the MVVM pattern. With MVVM you can use a property binding to control when the overlay is shown. We have some guides on MVVM and Xamarin.Forms that can help get you started [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_bindings_to_mvvm/). [Here](http://blog.falafel.com/loading-indicators-and-automatic-viewmodel-refresh-in-xamarin-forms/) is a blog post that shows an example too.

Comment: Future readers. The 2nd link to falafel's blog post can be found here
https://web.archive.org/web/20150928122509/http://blog.falafel.com/loading-indicators-and-automatic-viewmodel-refresh-in-xamarin-forms/

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
            
    this.layoutLoadingSpinner.IsVisible = true;
    this.layoutContent.IsVisible = false;

    // Load slow-loading model on a separate thread
    MySlowLoadingModel model = null;
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        model = new MySlowLoadingModel();
    });

    this.BindingContext = model;
    this.layoutLoadingSpinner.IsVisible = false;
    this.layoutContent.IsVisible = true;
}
```

*(Another option that avoids async/await is to call `MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread()` inside the `Task.Run`)*

An unfortunate side-effect is that any code run on the second thread becomes very difficult to debug. It seems the Xamarin debugger doesn't work right with multiple threads.